# How do I get my ART USB Dual Pre preamp to work?

Tags: drivers, usb, sound

I am using Audacity. I have an [ART USB Dual Pre](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00120XDEM) preamp. Ubuntu is not recognizing it whatsoever. I am able to record in Audacity, but it is using the mic that is built into my computer (which is a compaq Presario CQ50) instead of the one plugged into the preamp.

How do I get Ubuntu to recognize the preamp that is plugged into my computer? Something tells me it has to do with the installation of the preamp software. It came with a installation CD, but when I go to "install", the nothing happens. I can view what is on the CD, but there is no installing of anything. Please help!

Comment: Does the CD carry *Linux* drivers or software?

Answer (score 1):

Does the installation CD come with a Linux version? If not, there's a small chance that you might be able to use Wine to install the Windows version. Barring that, you may be out of luck unless someone writes a Linux driver for your preamp.

If, however, the preamp simply presents itself as a mic or something, then my answer above doesn't apply. You can find out what information your computer can see for your preamp thus:

```
lsusb -v | less
```